# How to include a series of details in a div using jQuery only without using data-attributes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Please bear with me because I don't know how to explain this in a shorter way. All the info I'm posting here is just an example, which is why they sound weird.
So, I wanted to have sort of a character select page and I wanted to display attributes of each character in a separate div when you click on the character's portrait. Certain data will be displayed on the character card div.

I basically have a list of character portraits, like this [html]:

```
<ul id="char-list">
  <li id="greengirl">Green Girl</li>
  <li id="maroonman">Maroon Man</li>
  <li id="whitwoman">White Woman</li>
  <li id="blackboy">Black Boy</li>
</ul>

<div id="char-card">
  <div id="char-name"></div>
  <div id="char-hair-color"></div>
  <div id="char-eye-color"></div>
  <div id="char-mag-power"></div>
</div>
```

All characters have for example, three attributes: `hair-color`, `eye-color`, and `magical-power`.
I want to display this within the `#character-card` `div` when the user clicks on each character.

Now, I know I can set a `data-attribute` to each character stat like this:

```
  ...
  <li id="greengirl" data-eye-color="Green" data-hair-color="Green" data-mag-power="322">Green Girl</li>
  ...
```

And write my jQuery like this:

```
$('#char-list li').on('mouseup', function() {
  var eyeColor = $(this).data('eye-color'),
      hairColor = $(this).data('hair-color'),
      magPower = $(this).data('mag-power'),
      charName = $(this).text(),
      nameDiv = $('#char-name'),
      hairDiv = $('#char-hair-color'),
      eyeDiv = $('#char-eye-color'),
      magDiv = $('#char-mag-power');

  nameDiv.text(charName);
  hairDiv.text(hairColor);
  eyeDiv.text(eyeColor);
  magDiv.text(magPower);
});
```

This works with no issues, but I'm trying to do something that's rather complex and each character has a lot of data, including a quote for each character, 4 ability icons, health, mana, defense, etc. and I just don't think putting them all in data-attributes for each item would be efficient. If I follow that method, I'd have to edit the html itself and that would mean a very long and confusing html. I've already found one good way to make some attributes easy to apply via jQuery:

```
var greenHairList = '#greengirl, #blueboy'
...
$(greenHairList).attr('data-hair-color', 'Green')
```

This way, it will be applied via jQuery, leaving my html clean and uncluttered. However, this still uses data-attributes. I'd love it if there were any other ways to achieve what I want with minimal use of data-attributes, and addressing my issue with the `character-card` `div`. Thanks to anyone who can help!

Answer (score 0):

Why you need to use data for your details?

The best solution is create an object list with all your characters deteails. And add just a `data-id` for get the good data.

You can:

```
var characters = [
      {
      id: 1,
      firstname:"john",
      lastname:"Doe",
      mana:150,
      power:2000
      },
      id: 2,
      firstname:"Karl",
      lastname:"Kanung",
      mana:120,
      power:300
      }
    ];
```

When you create this list, you can add html element dynamicaly with `data-id` for your character:

This is just an example in loop:

```
    id = 3;
    characters.push({id: id, firstname: "Paul", lastname: "pool", mana: 500, power: 3000});
    charlist = $("<li></li>").attr("data-id",id);
    $("#char-list").append(charlist);
id++;
```

and know you need just to make a `onclick` function, get the `data-id` of element, check in object list the details to show and create the card.

The best is create just on card alredy in your **html** page and replace the value by your objects value.

This is one way.

Comment: Thank you for responding! It's cause I'm not so familiar with methods I can use with jQuery, which is why I asked. But thank you I will try this out. I still have a bit of a problem with it, though because I have over a hundred characters. Is there an easier way than your answer, if I do have over a hundred characters? I have 106 to be exact.

Comment: If you call your characters list by ajax method you can easly use my funtion loop. through this you can get all value and add good value in each object.